# pi_0 disintegration into 2 photons: why is speed of CM = speed of pi_0 in lab?

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, reference-frames

I'm trying to treat the question of relativistic pi_0 disintegration into 2 photons. I'm solving the problem in a reference frame where the CM of the 2 photons is at rest. I don't understand why we can say that beta_CM = beta_(pi_0), ie. why the speed of the pi_0 in the lab reference frame is equal to the speed of the center of mass of the 2 photons. Could someone please explain me why?

I would have thought those speeds would be different since the mass energy of the particle before disintegration would "transform" into more speed for the photons.

Please tell me if my question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple momentum conservation. In the CM of the pi_0 in the lab frame the pi_0 it is by definition at rest. To transform to the CM frame of the pi_0 from the lab frame it is simply the velocity of that particle in the lab frame. By momentum conservation in the CM frame of the pi_0, when it breaks up, the CM of the products it breaks up into has to be zero. So the CM of the products has to have the same velocity as the initial pi_0 in the lab frame.

Velocity is what is used to transform from the lab to the CM frame. Momentum is what is conserved in either frame.

That answers your question.

For the two photons in the CM frame they each have equal and opposite momentum. How much then is calculated from energy-mass conservation.